# Find max occurances of anumber in an array

Tags: java

I've an array {2,22,33,20,222}, passing input as 2. I want find max occurrences of a number for 2.

Output: 222
because 222 contains maximum 2's in given array.

Can some one help me to write sample java program of above requirement.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to be under the impression that StackOverflow is a site where you post a problem and get some code in return. This is in fact not the case. Your question will most likely be closed or even deleted shortly. To prevent this from happening in the future, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [take a look at the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular, [make yourself famlilar as to what is regarded as on-topic around here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest (I think) way to achieve that, is to convert each number of your data array to a `String`. Then you can count the occurrences of your input number in this `String`. Finally a comparator to find the one with the most occurrences will do the job:

```
/**
 * Will return the first number of the data array if none of the numbers contain the input number.
 */
public static int findNumberInArrayWithTheMostOccurrences(Integer[] data, int number) {
    //@formatter:off
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(String.valueOf(number));
    Optional<String> result = Arrays.asList(data).stream()
            .map(String::valueOf) //Convert each number to a String
            .max((stringNum1, stringNum2) -> {//Comparing 2 strings
                Matcher m = pattern.matcher(stringNum1);
                int timesOfString1 = 0;
                while (m.find())
                    timesOfString1++;

                m = pattern.matcher(stringNum2);
                int timesOfString2 = 0;
                while (m.find())
                    timesOfString2++;
                return timesOfString1 - timesOfString2;
        });
    //@formatter:on
    return Integer.parseInt(result.get());
}
```

And a test unit (JUnit):

```
@Test
public void mainTest() {
    Integer[] data1 = { 2, 22, 33, 20, 222 };
    assertEquals(222, findNumberInArrayWithTheMostOccurrences(data1, 2));

    //Check if it returns the first element of the array when all numbers do not contain it
    assertEquals(2, findNumberInArrayWithTheMostOccurrences(data1, 215));

    Integer[] data2 = { 2, 2224, 3351, 20141414, 22214 };
    assertEquals(20141414, findNumberInArrayWithTheMostOccurrences(data2, 14));
}
```